# React Babel/Jest initial setup

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, babeljs, snapshot

I'm currently trying to set up Jest in my React project. I have created a simple snapshot test for App.js. I heard that you cannot run Jest without Babel so I used `npm i babel-jest` to install them both at the same time. I feel like I have done everything the normal tutorials have asked me to do. However, when I run `npm run test' I get the following error message:

```
PS C:\XXXXXXXXXXX\git\react-project\client> npm run test

> react-project@0.1.0 test C:\XXXXXXXXXXXX\git\react-project\client
> jest

 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: C:\XXXXXXXXXX\git\react-project\client\src\App.test.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (6:32):

      4 | 
      5 | it ('renders correctly', () => {
    > 6 |   const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
        |                                ^
      7 |   expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
      8 | });

    Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
    If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.

      at Parser._raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:60:45)
      at Parser.raiseWithData (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:55:17)
      at Parser.expectOnePlugin (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:157:18)
      at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1180:18)
      at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:563:23)
      at Parser.parseUpdate (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:543:21)
      at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:527:17)
      at Parser.parseExprOps (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:343:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:308:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:263:21)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.303 s
Ran all test suites.
(node:15304) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
```

I feel like the solution is in this error message but I can really understand what they are asking me to do here. Any help would be great! Let me know if you need any more information!

react-project\package.json

```
    {
      "name": "react-project",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "client": "cd client && yarn start",
        "server": "nodemon server.js"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "express": "^4.16.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
      }
    }
```

react-project\server\server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'Helo From Express' });
});

app.post('/api/world', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(
    `I received your POST request. This is what you sent me: ${req.body.post}`,
  );
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

react-project\client\App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Hello
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

react-project\client\App.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderer } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from './App';

it ('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

react-project\client\package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^26.3.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share code and errors as formatted code snippets and plain text. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The message clearly says what needs to be done. A preset needs to be added to Babel config.

Comment: The requested changes have been made!